# AttributeError: dlsym(0x7fe512579830, EVP_CIPHER_CTX_reset): symbol not found

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7

I'm trying to use this [package pywebpush](https://github.com/web-push-libs/pywebpush), but I'm getting this error:

```
AttributeError: dlsym(0x7fe512579830, EVP_CIPHER_CTX_reset): symbol not found
```

This is the entire traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pywebpush/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    import http_ece
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/http_ece/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from pyelliptic import ecc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyelliptic/__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    from .openssl import OpenSSL
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyelliptic/openssl.py", line 310, in <module>
    OpenSSL = _OpenSSL(libname)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyelliptic/openssl.py", line 144, in __init__
    self.EVP_CIPHER_CTX_reset = self._lib.EVP_CIPHER_CTX_reset
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 375, in __getattr__
    func = self.__getitem__(name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 380, in __getitem__
    func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
AttributeError: dlsym(0x7fe512579830, EVP_CIPHER_CTX_reset): symbol not found
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_reset` doesn't exist in OpenSSL-1.0.2 (or earlier), only in OpenSSL-1.1

Comment: To check your OpenSSL version, is running `openssl version -a` on the command-line enough? What about `python -c 'import ssl; print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)'`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that [`pyelliptic` 1.5.8 has a bug](https://github.com/martinthomson/encrypted-content-encoding/issues/33#issuecomment-299907806). You might be able to fix it by downgrading to 1.5.7:

```
pip install pyelliptic==1.5.7
```

[`pyelliptic` is actually deprecated](https://github.com/yann2192/pyelliptic), so avoid it if you can help it. Try uninstalling it with `pip uninstall pyelliptic` and then see if you broke any dependencies by running `pip check`.